# Performance point dashboard designer services problem

Tags: sharepoint-2010, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

when i try to add data source from analysis services to dashboard designer then i choose localhost as my server, an error message appears, it tels me "performance point is not well configured"...i don't know where the problem is???????

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the PerformancePoint Service configured correctly.

Configure *Secure Store* Service Application: generate a new key and create a pass phrase.
Make sure you have created an unattended service account for PerformancePoint.  Under *Application Management*, go to *Manage service applications*.  Click *PerformancePoint Service Application Settings* and enter the user name and password of your unattended service account in the *Secure Store and Unattended Service Account* area.

PerformancePoint is different than some of the other applications: it creates its own Secure Store account.

You should now be able to create your data source, assuming your unattended service account has permissions to whatever data source you are trying to access.